# Compiled image from graalvm not printing to standard out

Tags: clojure, graalvm

Graalvm version: graalvm-ce-19.0.0

Clojure version: Clojure 1.10.0

Leiningen 2.9.0 on Java 11.0.2 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

In my project (https://github.com/slifin/beeline) if I run

`lein run "{\":select\" [\":b\"]}"`

I get

`["SELECT b"]`

as I expected but if I do

`lein native-image`

and run

`./beeline-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT "{\":select\" [\":b\"]}"`

I get no output, though I know my program is running because if I change the input I get errors that make sense for my program, what's stopping it from printing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `(flush)` at the end of your main function.